Polynomials with equal magnitude on the unit circle
Let $p(z), q(z)$ be non-constant polynomials of the same degree n such that $|p(z)| = |q(z)|$ on the unit circle (where $|z| = 1$) and all their zeros are in the interior of the unit disk.
I'm trying to prove that in that case it must be that $q(z) = ap(z)$ for some (complex) $a$.
My initial instinct is to try and somehow use the fact that for $f(z) = \frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$ we have $|f(z)| = c > 0$ on the boundary $|z| = 1$ and perhaps invoke the maximum modulus principle somehow, asserting that any singularity of $f(z)$ (where only $q(z) = 0$) inside the unit disk would be a pole, hence f(z) would tend to $\infty$ in a neighborhood of that point, contradicting the maximum modulus principle.
But this seems off since (For example) my understanding is that to invoke max modulus principle I would need $f(z)$ to be continuous on the closure of the domain in question (the open disk), e.g. including any 'puncture points' where those aforementioned singularities would arise?
Any direction would be appreciated how to approach this otherwise!

It was a year long course covered pretty much everything you’d expect, rouches theorem, analytic continuation, möbius transforms etc. will look at link for clues thank you for lead

You have $f(z) = \frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$ where $\vert f(z)\vert = 1$ for $z \in S^1$ and $\lim_{z\to \infty }f(z) = \alpha\in \mathbb C-\big\{0\big\}$ [this is where $\text{degree }p=\text{degree }q$ is used].
$f$ is analytic in the annulus $1-\delta \lt \vert z \vert \lt \infty$  for $\delta \gt 0$ small enough
thus $g(z) = f\big(z^{-1}\big)$ is analytic in $B\big(0, \frac{1}{1-\delta}\big)$ with $g(0):=\lim_{z\to 0}g(z) = \alpha$, i.e. a removable singularity we define over. Now $g$ has no zeros in $\overline B\big(0,1\big)$ and is constant on it's boundary thus $g$ is constant by maximum and minimum modulus theorems [or use max modulus on $\frac{1}{g(z)}$ instead of the latter].  Thus $\vert \alpha \vert =1$ and $g(z)=f\big(z^{-1}\big)=\alpha\implies f(z)=\alpha$ on the annulus $1-\delta \lt \vert z \vert \lt \infty$.  Conclude $p(z) - \alpha\cdot q(z) =q(z)\cdot \big(f(z)- \alpha\big)=0$ for e.g. all $z\in B\big(1,\delta\big)\implies p(z) = \alpha\cdot q(z)$.

thank you! quick question on that last implication - this is because the functional relationship $f(z) - \alpha = 0$ holds on a domain with a limit point inside of it, hence it holds over all of $\mathbb{C}$? e.g. using the identity theorem?

That should do it.  You can also observe that $p(z)-\alpha \cdot q(z)$ is a polynomial function so it has finitely many zeros if is not the zero polynomial.

There is a theorem that a rational function that maps the unit circle to itself is a finite Blaschke product ( times a constant), this would do it.

That blaschke business I actually didn’t cover in my course so would hope to find slightly more elementary methods. I’ll look at it for inspiration though thank you

@giorgio: It seems to be covered OK in the book Rudin, Real and Complex Analysis.  The fact that the (finite)Blaschke product maps the circle to the circle is not hard to see. Perhaps Conway, Complex Analysis is also a source.
